# PDFLatex Printing Preview - French Cursive environment

Tags: pdftex, printing, preview, french, evince

I wanted to had a maxime to my latex book. 
Here is document viewed with Evince

[image]

here the document viewed with the preview application in printing windows of Evince

[image]

here the document viewed with the preview application in printing windows of acroread

[image]

The problem occurs when I try to print with the Evince reader. I get the non desirable result of Figure 2, while with acroread I don't have this problem.

I add that this maxime is a "french cursive environment" and here is the file that you can compile

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1.3in,top=1.1in,bottom=1.1in, includefoot,includehead,headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.62\textwidth}%
   { \fontfamily{frc}\selectfont
   Le fou a chant\'e 17 fois \\
   Puis il est mort de d\'esespoir \\
   Dans un champ de labiales carnivores \\
   Tous les tombeaux se sont ouverts \\
   Pour voir passer le mort vainqueur \\ 
   L'alcool s'est fig\'e sur ton verre \\
   Ta cigarette tombe sur ton coeur \\
   Et tu cherches une v\'erit\'e par-del\`a l'espace \\
   Ouais, tu cherches une v\'erit\'e par-del\`a l'espace}
\end{minipage}
\begin{flushright}
Le Chant du fou, Hubert-F\'elix Thi\'efaine \\
\end{flushright}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.1mm}%
\end{document}
```

My system configuration is: 
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) 
Evince 3.21.4 
Debian testing

Comment: You should show a complete example, not only a snippet from your preamble. (I don't have evince and so won't be able to test myself). Btw: don't use the aecompl package, you don't need it nowadays. Also the spacing after line 4 of your text is wrong/too small, you are doing something curious there.

Comment: ok, I gave the code to compile

Comment: I don't see such problem with evince on my Linux.

Comment: @MajidAbdolshah have you tried printing it? It looks fine on screen for me in Evince, but when I print it our Canon printer does not like it, I get an invalidfont error from the printer. Which Evince and LaTeX versions are you using?

Comment: As I said I can't test with evince (but the font is a bitmap font, so this could be the source of the problem), but it is obvious that font needs a much larger baselineskip or baselinestretch.

Comment: @dalief, Yes I checked that too. It seems fine. Maybe it is related to the problem Ulrike stated.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on TeX Live 2016, Ubuntu 16.04, evince 3.18.2

Comment: Why do the posted images say this is but one of several pages? The `.tex` file suggests it is but a single page.

Comment: I can confirm the problem with evince 3.22 on Debian unstable. It seems it is not a bug related to evince because I also have an error when trying to print the pdf with lp/lpr commandline. The error is "Nothing to print". I uploaded [the pdf](https://webcloud.zaclys.com/index.php/s/SJYBC34pH1nfhYp) if you want to try to reproduce the printing issue.

Comment: Correction: I just tried to print from the firefox embedded viewer which is called by owncloud (see link in my previous comment) and it printed fine. The problem *is* related to evince so but also affect lp/lpr. I guess the pdf has some issues handled by the embedded viewer and not by evince/lp/lpr.

Comment: that's constructive.
so it wouldn't be a bug of this unstable version of evince ? Is that evince using lp/lpr ?